# Git-friendly PowerShell package structure

Tags: git, powershell, github, powershell-2.0, nuget

I have a number of script (.PS1) and module (.PSM1) files that I would like to version control (I'm planning to use Github).  I'm hoping to deploy them as a package, perhaps by using NuGet.

I have the following directory structure:

```
|-My Documents
   |-WindowsPowerShell
     |-Modules
       |-Com.Foo.Bar.ModuleA
         |-Com.Foo.Bar.ModuleA.psm1
       |-Com.Foo.Bar.ModuleB
         |-Com.Foo.Bar.ModuleB.psm1
     |-Scripts
       |-Samples
         |-foobar.ps1
         |-other non-script files that I would like to version
```

I'm using the `WindowsPowerShell` folder to make it easier to use the code.

I've already created the Github repo (which created the README.md file).

PowerShell-related questions:

- Is using the Java-esque file and folder naming conventions a good practice for modules, especially if I want to treat them as a package?  Is this true of scripts as well?  Is there a better structure?
- If use a non-standard scripting directory (not `WindowsPowerShell`),can I modify my profile (Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1) to find it?

Git-related questions:
 - Should I clone this repo to the default directory (My Documents\GitHub) or to WindowsPowerShell?
 - If I use the GitHub directory, should I move the existing files to the new directory (child of GitHub)?

Answer (score 0):

Git-related answers:

You do not need to move the files. Do `git init` in the `WindowsPowerShell` folder (or in a sub-folder if you want to version control them independently). This will create a `.git` folder with a repository for version controlling the files below the `WindowsPowerShell` directory.

Then push to Github if you wish. You don't really need to if it is just version control you are after. You get that by just creating the repository.